# Tikz seems to be formatting differently every time

Tags: tikz-pgf, formatting, cv

I an currently formatting a page with the `tikz` package. I created a command to insert a vertical line and text above it. Sadly the formatting seems to be different every time it is called (there are spaces where no spaces are declared).

As you can see here:
[image]

What's going on there?

My code:

```
% !TeX program = lualatex
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

%font encoding & formatting
\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Arial}
\usepackage[document]{ragged2e}

%language
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{lipsum}

%Styles
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}
\usepackage{atbegshi}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\definecolor{bluey}{RGB}{12,3,150}



\newcommand{\sep}[1]{
    \vspace{0.5cm}
    {\color{blue} \large \textbf{#1}}\\
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw [blue, fill=blue] (-2,0.5) circle [radius=0.17];
        \draw [blue, line width = 1.5pt] (-1.75,0.5) -- (2.5,0.5);
        \draw [lightgray, line width = 1.5pt] (2.5,0.5) -- (11,0.5);
    \end{tikzpicture}

}

%header format
\newcommand\HeaderTwo{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
    \fill[bluey]
    (current page.north west) -- (current page.north east) --
    ([yshift=2cm]current page.north east|-current page text area.north east) --
    ([yshift=3cm]current page.north west|-current page text area.north west) -- cycle;
    \end{tikzpicture}%
}

\begin{document}

\HeaderTwo
\sep{My very very long foo Text}
\vspace{0.5cm}
\lipsum[1]

\sep{Another very very long foo text}
\vspace{0.5cm}
\lipsum[2]

\clearpage
\HeaderTwo


\sep{Another very very long foo text}
\vspace{0.5cm}
\lipsum[3]

\end{document}
```

Comment: You are using `\HeaderTwo` at the beginning of the page. This makes the `\vspace` visible as latex thinks you have started the page already. You should probably use it as header and won't have any issues anymore.

Comment: @nox I'm afraid I can't follow your explanation. How do I define it as a header? You cannot see it on my picture, but on page two I did the same and that was formatted properly. Also the linewidth is not always the same, it seems to be smaller some times (more or less randomly)

Comment: Fastest fix: put two empty lines between your `Headertwo` definition and your `sep`. The line width is unaffected, that is probably an aliasing problem with your screen. Zoom in (or print) to see constant line width.

Comment: Note, this is not a fix, but just shifts everything down, I'll post an answer in a sec.

Comment: See my edited answer, I fixed the first page position offset by adjusting `\headheight` for a 12pt doc and added a `\par` I forgot in `\HeaderTwo`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A very handy package to debug this, if you have no idea what's going on, is `showframe`. Using this with your code, you will see that your code just shifts down the first section title of the second page, rather than fixing the issue. The problem is that `\vspace{0.5cm}` of your `\sep` command. It will produce vertical space of the specified amount, but only if it's not at the beginning of a page. This is probably the desired behavior for titles and headings of sections etc., because that way the heading is positioned at the top of the page rather than shifted down. However, you put something at the beginning of the page (your tikz picture of `\HeaderTwo`). Although it is not intended to be put on the body of the page, latex doesn't know that. So latex sees this picture and afterwards, `\vspace` produces its space.

Here is how the second page of your code actually looks like:

[image: yourresult]

To avoid that, I suggested to use a header instead (that's why we have it after all). In the following I made use of the `fancyhdr` package which you already had in your preamble. The header is not part of the body of the page, so latex properly recognizes when `\vspace` should produce it's space.

I added a `\par` in your `\sep` macro, that way you don't have to prepend an empty line. Also, I loaded the `showframe` package and deleted the unnecessary `\vspace`s you should avoid in your main document.

Finally I commented out the `Arial` font, as I don't have it installed on my system. My result with

```
% !TeX program = lualatex
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

%font encoding & formatting
\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}
\usepackage{fontspec}
%\setmainfont{Arial}
\usepackage[document]{ragged2e}

%language
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{lipsum}

%Styles
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}
\usepackage{atbegshi}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\definecolor{bluey}{RGB}{12,3,150}

\newcommand{\sep}[1]{
    \par\vspace{1cm}%
    {\color{blue} \large \textbf{#1}}\\%
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw [blue, fill=blue] (-2,0.5) circle [radius=0.17];
    \draw [blue, line width = 1.5pt] (-1.75,0.5) -- (2.5,0.5);
    \draw [lightgray, line width = 1.5pt] (2.5,0.5) -- (11,0.5);
    \end{tikzpicture}%
}

%header format
\lhead{\HeaderTwo} % defines your header as header in pagestyle fancy
\pagestyle{fancy} % loads it
\setlength{\headheight}{14.5pt} % corrects header height for 12pt document

\newcommand\HeaderTwo{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]%
    \fill[bluey]%
    (current page.north west) -- (current page.north east) --%
    ([yshift=2cm]current page.north east|-current page text area.north east) --%
    ([yshift=3cm]current page.north west|-current page text area.north west) -- cycle;%
    \end{tikzpicture}%
    \par%
}

\usepackage{showframe}


\begin{document}
\sep{My very very long foo Text}
\lipsum[1]

\sep{Another very very long foo text}
\lipsum[2]
\clearpage

\sep{Another very very long foo text}
\lipsum[3]
\end{document}
```

looks like the following:

[image: result1]
[image: result2]